# Android - Add Custom View to ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a `ListView`, and I have a custom `View`, `PostView`.

How would I go about creating a `new PostView()`, and adding it to the `ListView` via `.addFooterView()`, but still being able to access the object representation of the `PostView`.

Right now I'm trying:

```
// the footer
p = new PostView( this );

p.setTargetUri( C.API_CONTENT );
p.setRenderMode( PostView.MODE_TEXT | PostView.MODE_IMAGE );

commentListView.addFooterView( p );
```

But that is failing, when I try to access the should have been inflated XML components.

Mainly:

```
public void setRenderMode( int renderMode )
{
  this.renderMode = renderMode;

  // fails
  this.postImagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.new_post_image_preview );
}
```

Am I going about this wrong? I have an `onFinishInflate()` defined, but maybe I'm prematurely accessing the Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to just have a super custom List Adapter, that was capable of returning different types of views, and manually adding a header and footer view around the generated list content.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hang on to the instance in a member variable instead of calling findViewById later?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This line: `this.postImagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.new_post_image_preview );
}` is called and defined inside of `PostView.class`. So, I'm not sure when that particular XML is available for access.

Answer (score 0):

Is your setRenderMode within PostView or the Activity that uses PostView?

If it is in the activity, you should be doing:

```
this.postImagePreview = (ImageView)p.findViewById( R.id.new_post_image_preview );
```

with p being a reference to your PostView that you have created.

Comment: It is within `PostView`. You'll see after I create a new `PostView`, I call `
p.setRenderMode( PostView.MODE_TEXT | PostView.MODE_IMAGE );`, before I attach it to the `ListView` as a footer.

Comment: Ah yes I see. It does seem that you are attempting to get the view too early then. How about using the oncreate() method instead. I think there is one of those for View objects.